# Installing VirtualBox disables Forefront

Tags: virtualbox, microsoft-forefront-2010

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad T520, less than a year old, running Windows 7 Ultimate.

After I install VirtualBox (it has happened with several versions), Forefront Endpoint Protection 2010 no longer starts automatically on startup. The icon in the notification is red and I need to open the program and click "Turn On". It stays on after that.

I did not find anything of interest in Event Viewer.

How can I find what is stopping Forefront from loading?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I **AM** the system administrator.

Comment: We had to be sure, you understand. :)

Comment: Venturing a guess, it has something to do with the virtual network adapter being installed - though I am not sure how to troubleshoot it. It might be hard to test, but if you install VBox first, then Forefront does it work as expected?